# Foundation Grid doesn't fit

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, sass, zurb-foundation

I've got a problem with my grid when using Zurb's Foundation. My Plan: on small devices show two ul-elements next to each other (6 columns each) and on medium up I want all four elements in one row.
My HTML:

```
<footer>
  <div class="row">
    <ul>
      <li>Headline</li>
      <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Headline</li>
      <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Headline</li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Headline</li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

I'm using Sass for my stylesheets and the file looks like this:

```
footer {
  // bg-images and stuff

  .row {
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 2; 
  }
  ul {

    @include grid-column(6);

    li {

        list-style: none;
    }
    @media #{$medium-up} {
        @include grid-column(3);
    }
  }
}
```

Here comes the problem: on small devices, every ul is in its own row, on medium and up there are three in a row, the fourth one is one the next.
Any suggestions, where I made a mistake?

Thanks a lot!
Florian

EDIT: The outputted CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:40.063em) {
  footer ul {
    padding-left: 0.9375rem;
    padding-right: 0.9375rem;
    width: 25%;
    float: left; }}
```

Also this:

```
*, *:before, *:after { -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: any added padding or margin?? sass looks fine. as it is happening in small as well medium screens i would look at padding and margin applied on the elements.

Comment: No, nothing on top of the basic foundation styling

Comment: Can you post the css generated? Or a link to the site?

Comment: Site is still in development. I added the compiled CSS in my question!

Comment: Oddly enough, when wrapping the uls in divs and applying '.small-6.medium-3.columns' as a class, everything works as it's supposed to.

Comment: that is wierd..the css generated works the same way as that of giving '.small-6.medium-3.columns'

Comment: Indeed. But I have a soluten now, which is fine for me. I wrapped every ul-element with a div.footer-block and applied to them the @include grid-column(3/6). This works and my HTML is still quite clean.

Answer (score -1):

When using the grid in foundation you have to specify your column divs:

In your example, to get the small devices to show 2 uls and medium devices to show four uls you need to do this:

```
<footer>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 medium-3 columns">
    <ul>
      <li>Headline</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 medium-3 columns">
    <ul>
      <li>Headline</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 medium-3 columns">
    <ul>
      <li>Headline</li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 medium-3 columns">
    <ul>
      <li>Headline</li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="footer-sec">
        <p>&copy; my site | and so on</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

You should not need any custom stylesheets to achieve this when using foundation. It is part of foundation's function to make this easy to do without needing to write custom stylesheets.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. I used a technique explained here: [Get Real with a Semantic Grid](http://zurb.com/university/lessons/42). Besides it works well on all other parts of the site!